# how to delete a build monitor view in jenkins

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I used the jenkins "Build Monitor Plugin" to build a monitor view, but after I renamed the view,  a new view was created, now I want to delete the old one,but I couldn't find a place for it, anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the way to do it, from the UI still I didn't find a place where I can just click on "delete" like other views. But we can delete it from the jenkins config file.
So go to jenkins_home, and edit the config.xml, and find the "listview" which contains the build monitor view you want to delete, then delete that part of the code, it will be fine after.

If you are using jenkins through kubernetes, first login to kubernetes by 
   kubectl exec -it podname -- /bin/bash, then go to var/jenkins_home

Answer (score 5):

Go to newly created view and click on "Add/remove items". This will take you to a new config view.
In the left hand side panel, there would be "Delete View". Just click on that. It should remove your Monitor view.

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the cog in the top right then on configure in the subsequent menu and this will take you back to the view configuration screen where you can click delete view on the left like for other views

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

1. Go to the monitor view
2. Click on gear(Settings) icon on right top
   corner
3. Click on configure button
4. Delete view option will be present On the left hand side.

Option 2:

Just go to the monitor view url and append 'delete' at end.
It will ask for confirmation to delete the view.
e.g.- https://jenkinsurl:8080/view/viewname/**delete**